# SQL SELECT max value for each of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem trying to build a select query in SQL Server.

Let's say I have a table called `TicketInformation`, which has an `ID`, a `Date` and a `TicketID` - like this:

```sql
|  ID | Date  | TicketID |
+-----+-------+----------+
|  1  | 12/20 |    1     |
|  2  | 12/21 |    1     |
|  3  | 12/22 |    1     |
|  4  | 12/20 |    2     |
|  5  | 12/21 |    2     |
|  6  | 12/22 |    2     |
```

What I want is to create a select that will only return the max ID of each `TicketID` and omit the rest, in the example above I would need IDs 3 and 6, but I can't figure how to make the query.

Comment: max + group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TicketID, MAX(ID)
FROM TicketInformation
GROUP BY TicketID
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @JeremyCaney, i'd generally agree, but for such trivial piece of code, it would seem a bit of overkill to try to explain anything

Comment: I think the aggregate with a grouping requires some explanation for new comers—otherwise they wouldn’t have had this question, presumably. That said, the question is now closed, so it may not matter.